# run powershell script from azure datafactory pipeline custom activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is it possible to run Powershell script from azure data factory pipeline as an activity, I have a UC where I need to move all the processed files from "input" folder to a folder called "processed" in Data Lake. I does have a powershell script for the same, however I want this to get executed from a Data Factory PipeLine.

> what i did was created a custom ".Net dll" that would call a ".BAT"
>   which in turn calls ".ps1", then I have integrated custom ".Net dll" as an activity in a pipeline but that does not seems to be working

please suggest if it is the write way of doing the above UC or there is any better solution for it.

Comment: Based on your description, you only need to move files from one folder to another? Then why not just use a Copy activity for your UC?

Comment: thanks Yitao for your comments, the copy activity will just copy the files but it won't move the files, if that's the case I will have to move the files manually from source once it gets copied to destination using copy activity

Answer (score 0):

So I had similar requirement in my case as well, I had to move files once the files were imported in our Azure database. What I did was create a pipeline which had the below:

1. Created Copy data activity to copy files from the main folder to the processed folder in Azure file share server.
2. Upon success of the copy activity I added a delete activity which deleted the files.

Hope this helps.